# while executing loop the error is list indices must be intergers,not tuple

Tags: list, numpy, typeerror, lis

I want to store all the iteration output in a matrix(of size 200x200).
While executing the code : got the error at the

```
for t in (T2/Taw)*np.arange(-Taw,Taw-1):
    i=i+1;
    j=0;
    for Fd in (B/Taw)*np.arange(-Taw,Taw-1):
        j=j+1;
        val1=1-abs(t)/T2;
        val2=pi*T2*val1;
        val3=Fd+mu*t+np.spacing(1);
        val4=val2*val3;
        ambg[j,i]=np.abs(val1*(sin(val4)/(val4)))**2;


---> 62         ambg[j,i]=np.abs(val1*(sin(val4)/(val4)))**2;

              TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

Comment: Where do you initialize `i`?

Comment: before the first for loop

Comment: before the first for loop, i have written                                                      i=0;
ambg=[ ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ambg=[]` is a list.  It can only be indexed with an integer, e.g `ambg[i]`.   `ambg[i,j]` is the equivalent to `ambg[(i,j)]`, where `(i,j)` is a tuple.  Hence the error message.

If `ambg` was a list of lists, then it could indexed as `ambg[i],[j]`.  But lists of lists are often constructed by iteratively appending values to a list(s).

If you initialized `ambg=np.zeros((N,M))` where `i` and `j` will range over `range(N)` and `range(M)`, then your code should work.

However initializing a `numpy` array element by element like this is slow, and considered poor practice.  I haven't studied your code in detail, but it looks like you might be able to construct `ambg` with vector operations using  `T = (T2/Taw)*np.arange(-Taw,Taw-1)` and `FD = (B/Taw)*np.arange(-Taw,Taw-1)`.

For example `T[:,None]` is a single column array, and `FD[None,:]` a
single row array, that together can be used to calculate the NxN array based on all combinations of their values.

Experiment with something simpler like `I = np.arange(10)` and `J = np.arange(10)`, and look at `I[:,None]*J[None,:]`, or their sum, or difference, etc.